# call method in webpart

Tags: development, web-part, debugging

I'm trying to debug the code below. For some reason the GetUserProperties Method isn't called during debug. Can someone tell me how i'm able to call it? I wan't to display the user-properties in an extra tab on the my-sites..

```
    namespace CV.CV
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class CV : WebPart
    {

        Property propQualifications = null;
        string strQualifications = "";



        public Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyCollection GetUserProperties()
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyCollection oPropertyCollection = null;

            System.Security.PermissionSet ps = new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            ps.Assert();

            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext serviceContext = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext.Current;
            Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager upm = new Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

            oPropertyCollection = upm.PropertiesWithSection;

            propQualifications = oPropertyCollection.GetPropertyByName("Qualifications");
            strQualifications = propQualifications.ToString();

            //Console.WriteLine(strQualifications);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(propQualifications);

            System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();

            return oPropertyCollection;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a call to your method by overriding either the Page_Load or OnPreRender method of your Web Part.

Comment: can you be a little more specific? im new to the game ;)